# OpenCL: get PCIe Bus for Intel GPU

Tags: opencl, intel

**Question:** Is there any (Vendor-Specific) way to get the PCIe Bus of a Intel Graphic-Card ( or to get any other unique-id for Intel GPU (uniqueness per vendor)).

I know i can't get such information without using Vendor-Specific-Extensions. I know for AMD that with *cl_amd_device_topology*, i can get this information. And for NVIDIA, i can get it with *cl_nv_device_attribute_query* and *CL_DEVICE_PCI_BUS_ID_NV*.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but if working specifically with Intel GPUs on Linux using  Beigenet platform, then for most (not all, I believe Cherryview is an exception), the `CL_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID` returned using `clGetDeviceInfo` maps to PCIID of the GPU.
See [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/beignet/tree/src/cl_device_id.c) for the implementation and [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/beignet/tree/src/cl_device_data.h) for the mapping.

Using the standard Intel drivers on other platforms would require you to match the `CL_DEVICE_NAME` with output from either sysfs or [pciutils](https://github.com/gittup/pciutils) on Linux, and `Win32_DisplayControllerConfiguration.Caption` and `Win32_Bus.DeviceID` on Windows.

Comment: unfortunatel that is not the way to go for me, i want to use the Intel Platform with the opencl lib provided by Intel. Thanks.